# Error is only thrown when web app is deployed

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

My ASP.NET web app takes an image file and uploads it to Azure storage as a BLOB. It works fine when ran locally in both debug & release mode. The problem occurs when the app is deployed through its Azure web app. Unfortunately, because I cannot get the stack trace I can't quite figure out what's causing the issue but the only thing I can think of is the Azure storage is blocking it for security reasons, but it's set to allow calls from Azure services so I thought it would allow it.

Here's the function that the site calls to upload the image. This is the only function that's called from the action so it has to be throwing an exception here.

```
public async Task<bool> UploadFile(IFormFile file, string fileName, Vendor vendor)
    {
        string storageConnectionString = _config.GetConnectionString("Storage");
        CloudStorageAccount storage = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConnectionString);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storage.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        string nameFormatted = vendor.Name.Replace(" ", "").ToLower();
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(nameFormatted);
        await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
        using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
        {
            var blobRef = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
            await blobRef.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

And here's the error that is thrown when deployed.
[image: Eror]

Comment: Did you try adding permissions on the container? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#set-permissions-on-a-container

Comment: @KarthikGanesan No luck with that

Comment: Are you hosting this as an Azure App Service? Why can't you get the stack trace? Have you tried to enable App Service Logs or Application Insights? Any detailed errors there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I could not see any obvious issue in your code, actually you can remote debug your application on Azure WebApp by Visual Studio.

There are three offical blogs introduce how to remote debugging on Azure WebApp.

1. [Introduction to Remote Debugging on Azure Web Sites](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introduction-to-remote-debugging-on-azure-web-sites/)
2. [Remote debug your Azure App Service Web App](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/09/22/remote-debug-your-azure-app-service-web-app/)
3. [Troubleshoot an app in Azure App Service using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-dotnet-visual-studio)

You just need to follow the figure below to enable the `Debugging` feature of your App Service on Azure portal, then you can follow the blogs above to do it.

[image]

Hope it helps.